# Athena JDBC Parameterized Query not interpreting type correctly

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, amazon-athena

Getting this error - java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]AthenaJDBC Athena does not support the parameter type: java.lang.String.

I am using com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver as Athena JDBC driver.

```
Time startTime = new Time()
String sql = "SELECT AccountId FROM Accounts WHERE Create_Time = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject(1, startTime);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Above code is giving that error. I get the error even when using setTime() instead of setObject(). It's almost like its interpreting it as String. Any thoughts on how to correct this?

I also tried changing query to

```
String sql = "SELECT AccountId FROM Accounts WHERE Create_Time = cast(?, timestamp)";
```

But still getting same error - java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]AthenaJDBC Athena does not support the parameter type: java.lang.String.

Any thoughts on what it means?